# Which NoSQL database fits best for the following purpose?

Tags: database

I am now struggling to find a best database for the following purpose:
1. Store the online data every 0.1 second!
2. Easy to access the data in the database
3. Compatible for windows system
4. No need to be OpenSource Solution
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is alot of nosql db systems, most simplest for me are [redis](http://redis.io/) and [mongodb](http://mongodb.org/). 
I use redis for highload apps, and mongodb for easier access to data (if you came from sql world). Both have windows versions, both open sourced.

Comment: Thanks!Do you have any idea that whether the mongodb can handle the 0.1s data streaming?

Comment: Is depend on your traffic and what type of data do you wanna store (especially durability requirments), redis is much faster than mongo in simple operations (SET, GET), if you not afraid key-value store instead of document store use redis. Here is benchmark http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks, as you can see for 0.1 second you can perform 11000 SET operations for simple string data on single server!